# Getters and Setters, getting multiple fields

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, getter-setter

```
public class Teams : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string CombinedTeams
        {
            get
            {                   
                return Combined;
            }

            set
            {                    
                {                                               
                    CombinedTeams += value;
                    NotifiyPropertyChanged("Combined"); 
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifiyPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            if (null != p)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
            }
        }
        private string Combined
        {

            get
            {
                return " " + HomeTeam + " " + HomeScore + " - " + AwayScore + " " + AwayTeam;
            }
            set 
            {
                { 
                    Combined += value;
                }
            }
        }
        public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
        public string HomeScore { get; set; }
        public string AwayScore { get; set; }
    }
```

I got a problem, when trying combine my strings together and having one LONG string that contains all the values from when I parse my XML I only get the First set of values,

basically I get

`Team1 Score1 : Score2 Team2`

as opposed to 
 `Team1 Score1 : Score2 Team2  Team3 Score3 : Score4 Team4  Team5 Score5 : Score6 Team6`

I am binding my Control to `CombinedTeams`

could you guys help me out? I just want to store the previous string and then combine the new string with the old one, I cant see it being hard but this is confusing me and reading up on it makes me more confused...

Thanks,

John

Comment: I edited the above, but I am still struggling, I cant get my head around getters and setters and inotifiedproperty

Comment: Another small note to people using Inotifypropertychanged. You shouldn't call this.NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName) before you set the actual value. You are already notifying and then updating Combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the incorrect results is because you have one property referring to another property, and the second property always returns a specific value.

This block of code, when called from elsewhere, will return the results of some other variable called "Combined" which you have defined below...

```
public string CombinedTeams                      
{                      
    get                      
    {                                         
        return Combined;                      
    }                      
    ...
}           

private string Combined                        
{                        
    get                        
    {                        
        return " " + HomeTeam + " " + HomeScore + " - " + AwayScore + " " + AwayTeam;                        
    }
    ...
}
```

Everything else is academic because you're getter(s) essentially always return " " + HomeTeam + " " + HomeScore + " - " + AwayScore + " " + AwayTeam.

I suspect you will want to restructure your code to be something more like this

```
public class Teams : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string Combined; // Backing for CombinedTeams
    public string CombinedTeams
    {
        get
        {
            return Combined;
        }
        set
        {
            // This only concatinates values; Combined will get longer each time.
            Combined += value;
            // ViewModels should always notify after the vale has changed
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("CombinedTeams");
        }
    }

    // Adds a new team, assuming HomeTeam, HomeScore, AwayScore, and AwayTeam have been initialized
    public void AddTeam()
    {
        CombinedTeams = " " + HomeTeam + " " + HomeScore + " - " + AwayScore + " " + AwayTeam;              
    }                     
}
```

Certainly there are better ways to do that, but that should get you a start, I hope.

General rule (broken all the time by the code-ninjas, which is fine) is that a Property shouldn't do any calculations of it's own, it's really there to allow public access to private data in the class.

It might be worthwhile to run through a couple of articles on C# Properties. Here are some suggestions to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx and of course, some [Good Search Results](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=c#+properties&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=43339dc04ff0961e&biw=1366&bih=673)

Comment: EtherDragon I really appreciate your time in explaining and outlining this, Thank you

Comment: NP, glad to do it, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Your code concatenates the new value to an empty string (`last = ""`).
You probably want to concatenate to the previous value.

Comment: how would I store the last value?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are expecting, `last` is always initialized to "", so the += is irrelevant.

Seems like the class called Teams is really a game?

And I don't think setting HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HomeScore, AwayScore over and over again (and then saving this internally somehow) is a good way to keep track of multiple games.

Why don't you look at using a collection of games?

Try something like this:

In a GamesLib library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace GamesLib
{
    public class Game
    {
        public string HomeTeam { get; private set; }
        public string AwayTeam { get; private set; }
        public string HomeScore { get; private set; }
        public string AwayScore { get; private set; }

        public string Combined
        {
            get
            {
                return " " + HomeTeam + " " + HomeScore + " - " + AwayScore + " " + AwayTeam;
            }
        }

        public Game(string HomeTeam, string AwayTeam, string HomeScore, string AwayScore)
        {
            this.HomeTeam = HomeTeam;
            this.HomeScore = HomeScore;
            this.AwayTeam = AwayTeam;
            this.AwayScore = AwayScore;
        }
    }

    public class Games : List<Game>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string CombinedTeams
        {
            get
            {
                var str = "";
                foreach (Game g in this)
                {
                    str += g.Combined;
                }
                return str;
            }
        }

        public new void Add(Game g)
        {
            base.Add(g);
            if ( PropertyChanged != null ) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CombinedTeams"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

In a console program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using GamesLib;

namespace TestHarness
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var gs = new GamesLib.Games();
            gs.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(gs_PropertyChanged);
            var g = new Game("hometeam", "awayteam", "1", "0");
            gs.Add(g);
            g = new Game("lions", "bears", "1", "0");
            gs.Add(g);
            Console.WriteLine("Final result:" + gs.CombinedTeams);
        }

        static void gs_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var gs = sender as Games;
            Console.WriteLine("Changed: " + gs.CombinedTeams);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code but I am still not getting it, I think I am just not seeing the problem I been looking at this stupid thing for like 2 hours

Comment: @John Antony Daniel Nolan I have posted a full example for you.